# Link C variable to Lua

Tags: c, lua

I'm looking for a solution to bind a C variable (integer, double, normal C string or similar) to Lua. Lua should be able to modify this variable (in C context). I'm not looking for a solution to call a C function at all (from Lua to get the reference to that variable). I also do not want to use any external library for this (Lua API will do fine). I have seen that LuaBridge solve this (existing project using this: https://github.com/Malaxiz/Third/blob/network/Fifth/CGame.cpp#L240), but as I said, no external libraries and definitely not C++.

Example of use:

C code

```
typedef struct Instance {
    int test;    /* The variable I want to link to Lua (and be able to modify it)*/
} Instance;

int main() {
    lua_State* L = lua_open();
    Instance instance;
    instance.test = 5;
    /* ... */
}
```

And in Lua:

```
instance.test = instance.test + 5
print(instance.test)   -- Should be 10
```

Back to C:

```
int main() {
    ...
    printf("%i\n", instance.test);    /* Should be 10 here too */
}
```

Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

> I'm not looking for a solution to call a C function at all.

You'll have to. There will be a call to C function, always. Even if it might be not explicit on Lua side, it will be there.
Typically you will set metatable on `instance` object that lives in Lua. It will catch reads and writes to that object, and redirect those actions to C side by calling C functions.

Comment: What I meant was that I don't want to call a C function from Lua to bind the variable (get reference e.t.c).

Comment: Lua values and native C values are separate entities. You'll have to either store it on single side - in Lua VM or in C, means calling func to store/read values across VM/native border. Or make other calls to synchronize values of two entities, if you want to store those values on both sides. Function calls to C either way.

Comment: Can you show me a workaround? And also, can you explain how LuaBridge does it? In LuaBridge you can successfully store a reference to, say, C integer and change it in a Lua script without calling a wrapper function.

Comment: Wrappers called implicitly by Lua. Read about Lua metatables and `__index` / `__newindex` metamethods. That's the building blocks for any bridging lib.

Comment: I'll look into it, thanks. It would be good if you improved your answer and maybe show an example.

Answer (score 1):

It is the "homework" for Lua/C programmer, but for google sake:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <lauxlib.h>
#include <lualib.h>

typedef struct Instance Instance;

struct Instance {
    int test1;
    double test2;
};

// linstance.c {

    static const char *const tname = "Instance";

    enum { f_test1, f_test2 };
    static const char *const fmap[] = { "test1", "test2" };

    static int
    l_get(lua_State *L) // (t, k) -> v
    {
        Instance *inst = *(Instance **)luaL_checkudata(L, 1, tname);

        switch (luaL_checkoption(L, 2, NULL, fmap)) {
            case f_test1: lua_pushinteger(L, inst->test1); break;
            case f_test2: lua_pushnumber(L, inst->test2); break;
        }
        return 1;
    }

    static int
    l_set(lua_State *L) // (t, k, v)
    {
        Instance *inst = *(Instance **)luaL_checkudata(L, 1, tname);

        switch (luaL_checkoption(L, 2, NULL, fmap)) {
            case f_test1: inst->test1 = luaL_checkinteger(L, 3); break;
            case f_test2: inst->test2 = luaL_checknumber(L, 3); break;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    void
    pushInstance(lua_State *L, Instance *instance)
    {
        Instance **ud = lua_newuserdata(L, sizeof(*ud));
        *ud = instance;

        if (luaL_newmetatable(L, tname)) {
            lua_pushcfunction(L, l_set);
            lua_setfield(L, -2, "__newindex");
            lua_pushcfunction(L, l_get);
            lua_setfield(L, -2, "__index");
            lua_pushstring(L, tname);
            lua_setfield(L, -2, "__metatable");
        }
        lua_setmetatable(L, -2);
    }

// }

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(L);

    Instance instance = { -1, -1.0 };

    pushInstance(L, &instance);
    lua_setglobal(L, "instance");

    luaL_dostring(L, "print(instance.test1, instance.test2)");
    luaL_dostring(L, "instance.test1 = 3.14; instance.test2 = 3.14");
    luaL_dostring(L, "print(instance.test1, instance.test2)");
    printf("%d\t%g\n", instance.test1, instance.test2);

    if (luaL_dostring(L, "print(instance.UNKNOWN)")) {
        printf("%s\n", lua_tostring(L, -1));
        lua_pop(L, 1);
    }

    lua_close(L);
    return 0;
}
```

---

```
-1  -1
3   3.14
3   3.14
[string "print(instance.UNKNOWN)"]:1: bad argument #2 to '__index' (invalid option 'UNKNOWN')
```

Comment: This was very helpful. It's a little hard to read with your coding-style. So get function is called when doing index set/get with help of metatable. Didn't know the checkudata existed.